# code into def function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm brand new in Python and trying to solve one of my exercises:
Below is a code describing growth of money, which started at $100, and which grows over time at a rate of 3% per year. The balance at the end of a given year is equal to balance*rate from the year before.

```
balance = 100.0
rate = 0.03

print(0, round(balance,2))
for n in range(1,11):
    balance = round(balance * (1 + rate), 2)
    print(n, round(balance,2))
```

I get desired output printed out each year for a total period of 10 years.
Now, how do I take that code above and turn it into a function with the following instructions? :

Write a function named compound that takes three inputs: balance, rate, and num_periods. That function should take the initial balance, a fixed interest rate, and the number of time periods over which the balance is to be compounded. You’ll want your function to return the current balance (i.e., the total of the principal plus all accrued interest) at the end of the function so that you know how much money you have if you would like to reinvest it.

I assume I should be getting exactly same output as with the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def compound(balance, rate, num_periods):
    for i in range(num_periods + 1):
        print(round(balance * (1 + rate)**i, 2))


print(compound(100, 0.03, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go is with a `lambda`:

```
compound = lambda balance, rate, num_periods: balance * ( 1 + rate)**num_periods
```

Usage:

```
print (round(comp_interest(100.0,0.03,10), 2))
```

Since a lambda function isn't acceptable to you, here's a function with formatted output, type hints and docstrings:

```
def compound(balance: float, rate: float, num_periods: float):
    """Calculate balance with compund interest

    Keyword arguments:

    balance: starting balance
    rate: interest rate(1 > rate > 0)
    num_periods: number of interest num_periods

    """
    for n in range(1, num_periods+1):
        balance *= (1 + rate)
        print(f"{n:2}, {round(balance,2)}") 
    return round(balance, 2)
```

When dealing with money, it's usually better to keep the rounding for display purposes only.  Always keep the actual amount in raw format.

Answer (score 0):

Your three inputs are balance, rate, and num_periods, which correspond with the variables balance, rate and the 2nd number in the range method. Your function should look pretty similar to the code above except with those variables being the inputs of the function:

```
def compound(balance, rate, num_periods):
    for n in range(1, num_periods):
        balance = round(balance * (1 + rate), 2)
    
    return round(balance, 2)
```

Note that using the round function inside the for-loop may lead to rounding errors. To avoid this, take our the round function inside the for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
def compound(balance, rate, num_periods):
    return balance * (1 + rate)**num_periods

print(compound(100, 0.03, 10))
```

This is basic time value of money problems. Note that num_periods is yearly in this case (as you said 10 years).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Very helpful. I was testing the below code and it does return one value as desired.

```
def compound(balance, rate, num_periods):
for n in range(1, num_periods):
    return balance * (1 + rate)**num_periods
print(compound(100, 0.03,10))
```

What am I missing, if I were to return running totals starting 0-10 years.
So it would look like this:

```
0 100.0
1 103.0
2 106.09
3 109.27
4 112.55
5 115.93
6 119.41
7 122.99
8 126.68
9 130.48
10 134.39
```

Answer (score 0):

Tahnks @tinstaafl, I can't use lamda as that's not part of the exercise.
This code returns almost what I need, though it should be shifted a bit but can't figure out how.

```
def compound(balance, rate, num_periods):
for n in range(1, num_periods):
    balance = round(balance * (1 + rate), 2)
    print(n, round(balance,2)) 
return round(balance, 2)
print(compound(100, 0.03, 10))
```

My desired output:

```
0 100.0
1 103.0
2 106.09
3 109.27
4 112.55
5 115.93
6 119.41
7 122.99
8 126.68
9 130.48
10 134.39
```